# Shift a single row over by one cell

Tags: r

The issue is that when I import my data, the variables I have for example (A, B, C) are not aligned correctly with their observations, and I was wondering if there was a way to just shift the column names (or entire row) over by one cell after my import step.

this is the code I have used to import my data

```
dat.met = read.table("/Users/test/Human.txt", sep="\t",header=T)

A B C 
1 M 1 1
2 F 2 2
3 F 1 1
4 F 2 2

  A B C 
1 M 1 1
2 F 2 2
3 F 1 1
4 F 2 2
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: sorry the example shifted over, it looks like the top plot, the column names are shifted one space over to the left so that the data belonging to variable A is really labeled as B.  I wish I could share my output but I work at a hospital and can't share the actual data.

Comment: Does `read.table(..., row.names = 1)` fix the problem?

Comment: yes it did thank you!